# How can I drop a BigQuery partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't want to delete tables one by one.
What is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to remove all partitions for the partitioned BQ table to be dropped.

Assuming you have gcloud already installed... do next:

Using terminal(check/set) GCP project you are logged in:

`$> gcloud config list` - to check if you are using proper GCP project.

`$> gcloud config set project <your_project_id>` - to set required project

Export variables:

`$> export MY_DATASET_ID=dataset_name;`

`$> export MY_PART_TABLE_NAME=table_name_;` - specify table name without partition date/value, so the real partition table name for this example looks like -> "table_name_**20200818**"

Double-check if you are going to delete correct table/partitions by running this(it will just list all partitions for your table):

```
for table in `bq ls --max_results=10000000 $MY_DATASET_ID | grep TABLE | grep $MY_PART_TABLE_NAME | awk '{print $1}'`; do echo $MY_DATASET_ID.$table; done
```

After checking run almost the same command, plus bq remove command parametrized by that iteration to actually DELETE all partitions, eventually the table itself:

```
for table in `bq ls --max_results=10000000 $MY_DATASET_ID | grep TABLE | grep $MY_PART_TABLE_NAME | awk '{print $1}'`; do echo $MY_DATASET_ID.$table; bq rm -f -t $MY_DATASET_ID.$table; done
```

Answer (score 1):

> The process for deleting a time-partitioned table and all the
>   partitions in it are the same as the process for deleting a standard
>   table.

So if you delete a partition table without specifying the partition it will delete all tables. You don't have to delete one by one.

```
DROP TABLE <tablename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete programmatically (i.e. java).
Use the sample code of [DeleteTable.java](https://samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/DeleteTable.java) and change the flow to have a list of all your tables and partitions to be deleted.
In case needed for deletion of specific partitions only, you can refer to a table partition (i.e. partition by day) in the following way:

```
String mainTable = "TABLE_NAME"; // i.e. my_table
String partitionId = "YYYYMMDD"; // i.e. 20200430
String decorator = "$";
String tableName = mainTable+decorator+partitionId;
```

[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/tree/5296465e2a9b253ed9e8faa07be3be1e9d308f9b/samples#getting-started-with-bigquery-samples) is the guide to run java BigQuery samples, and ensure to set your project in the cloud shell:

```
gcloud config set project <project-id>
```